# On a limit of permutation groups

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $E \subseteq \{1,2,\dots\}$ be a set of natural numbers such that for any $p,q \in E$ there exists $r \in E$ satisfying $p | r$ and $q | r$ (where $|$ is the ''divides'' relation). Let $S_p$ be the set of all bijective functions in $\{0,\dots,p-1\}$; the symmetric group on $p$ elements.

For $p,q \in E$ with $p|q$, we define the injective morphism $\phi_{p,q}\colon S_p \to S_q$ as follows: if $\sigma\in S_p$, $j \in \{0,\dots,q-1\}$, then we write $j = kp+\ell$, with $k \geq 0$, $\ell \in \{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$, and put
$$ \phi_{p,q}(\sigma)(j) = \sigma(\ell)+kp. $$
Equivalently, $\phi_{p,q}(\sigma)$ is the unique element $\tau \in S_q$ such that $\tau(j) = \sigma(j)$ for all $j \in \{0,\dots,p-1\}$ and $\tau(j+p) = \tau(j)+p$ for all $j \in \{0,\dots,q-1\}$. Clearly, $\phi_{p,q}(\sigma) \in S_q$ and $\phi_{p,q}$ is an injective morphism.

Observe that by the condition of the first paragraph, $\{\phi_{p,q} : p,q\in E,\ p | q\}$ is an [direct system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit#Direct_limits_of_algebraic_objects), and so the direct limit
$$\mathcal{S} :\!=  \varinjlim_{p\in E}{S_p} $$
exists.

My questions: **is this a ''known'' group? is there a neat description of this group?**

When $E$ is finite, then $\mathcal{S}$ is simply $S_{\max(E)}$, so we can suppose that $E$ is infinite.

Comment: I feel like [this paper](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/1c49887edfb1c45fa09bce57b198e525/adm40.pdf) might be relevant; your embeddings look close to the definition of _diagonal embedding_ given there.